# How can I change a turtle's status depending on specific conditions?

Tags: netlogo

I really need your help to fix a problem with my code.
Unfortunately, I am having difficulty by updating the status of turtles once a condition is satisfied.

It is a virus spread problem: each node, called human, has its own 'bag' which contains different items (virus and medicines).  The bag is made up of items from the neighbours that are linked to the chosen turtle.
The virus can come from a zombie at the beginning (t=0) and move from turtle to turtle, depending on what they decide to do. If a turtle picks up a virus (spread action), it can become infected.
The part of code that is giving me some problems is the following:

```
to spreading
   ask one-of humans                                                
  [ let choice one-of out-link-neighbors                              
      ifelse empty? bag                                        
        [ ifelse random-float 1  < p
          [action1 set bag lput act1 bag print "act1"]
          [action3 print "act3"]
        ]

        [spread set bag lput spreadvirus bag print "spreadvirus"
           if  [infected?] of choice                                 
               [become-infected] ]
        ]
   ]
    end
```

more specifically the part with *spread*.
What that part of code should do is to build for each randomly chosen turtle a bag made up by all the'items' from neighbours' bags, and transform that turtle according to what it chooses.

For example, as you can see in the figure below, at the beginning nodes 2,5 and 7 can be potentially infected because they are linked to the zombies. Each turtle can 'see' all its items plus all the items contained in its neighbours bags *(for example, 7 can see - and potentially choose - all the items from Z, from 8 - its bag is empty in this case - and from its own bag, made by historical stored items, i.e. past choices)*. Let's say that 7 picks the virus from the zombie (action 2, i.e. spread) and becomes infected. Node 5, that can see all the items contained in the lists of nodes 4 and 7, can become infected as well, depending on what it chooses. If 5 prefers an item from 4, that is a node not infected because in its own list there are only uninfected items, it becomes susceptible. If it chooses, among all, the infected item from 7, it becomes infected as well. And so on...

What I suspect is that the bags are not storing information from the neighbours as I want. This explains why no humans are becoming infected from the ifelse statements, but only susceptible and they change color in white and blue depending on their choices.

I am not getting any error from the code, so it is difficult for me to understand what I am really doing wrong. I also put some print to see what is not working, and it seems that the part of code with spread as action is the problem.
What I should expect is a list that contains all the items from turtle's neighbours. At each tick the turtle can choose what to do with those items (action1, spread, action3), by adding a new item, selecting an item from neighbours, or do nothing. This choice should be added to the turtle bag. This means that the list, at each tick, should be updated, taking into account all the elements from the neighbours, plus the selected action/element from the turtle. But the turtle becomes infected only if it chooses (spread) not a medicine from the neighbours, but a virus.

UPDATED after JenB answer and to better explain how the human breed should become infected:

The possible types of items that each bags can contain are new medicines, medicines from the same turtle or from neighbours and/or virus, for humans; only virus for zombies - I do not need to add elements to zombies' bags.
To better clarify: Once there is a link between one turtle and another one, these turtles can have access to all the items in their bags, respectively. When it is time to select an action, the turtle can have access to its own bag that contains all the items stored from the neighbours’ bags, as bags are made up of items (medicines and virus) from all the turtles linked to a chosen turtle. 
However, the turtle becomes infected only if it decides to select the action spread, and to select an item infected from the neighbors’ bags. 
After the choice, the element chosen is added to its own bag. 
I edited part of the code. What I did is to create a new bag for zombies, initialising with only "virus"; furthermore, I edited the part of code regarding 'to spread' as following:

```
    to spread

     set action1? false
     set spread? true
     ifelse any? out-link-neighbors with [infected?]
      [ print "Virus!" 
        set spreadvirus spreadvirus + 1
        become-infected]
      [ print "Medicine from neighbour"
        set spreadvirus spreadvirus + 1
        become-susceptible]
    end
```

But also in this way, I am not having humans that become infected. And I think that the bag that I am trying to build is not storing all the items from the turtle's neighbours. And this explains why turtles cannot become infected.

I hope you can help me to understand what I have done wrong.
Thank you for your time, effort and help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please only ask one question. For that question describe what is happening and what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Thanks JenB. I edited the post, deleting all the obsolete parts. To better explain my difficulty, I also added a flowchart that should explain the dynamics within the network. Please let me know if it is still not well explained. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a much clearer explanation of what should happen, but you still haven't told us what is happening. For example, you have print statements in there, is the appropriate output being printed (so the code is getting to that part) or is that bit of the code not being selected? Are you getting an error message? What does one of these lists look like?

I think you mean that the logic is not working. I suggest you put some more diagnostic prints at the top once you have selected the human:

```
ask one-of humans                                                
[ type "Neighbour count: " print count out-link-neigbors
  type "Bag at start: " print bag
  ifelse...
```

Then you can see why the selected path is being selected. It will also let you know if the variable contents aren't what you expect.

You have a comment that the line `set bag lput spreadvirus bag` is not working. So replace:

```
[ show one-of bag
  set bag lput spreadvirus bag     ;; NOT WORKING
  print "spreadvirus" ]
```

with

```
[ show bag
  set bag lput spreadvirus bag
  show bag
  print "spreadvirus" ]
```

to see what it is doing.

The other thing you can do to debug is replace `ask one-of human` with 'ask human 10` (or some other specific human). Find humans with different situations - one with only one neighbour for example, and try them out.

**UPDATED in response to comment**

The [6 2] is the contents of the bag. When you put act1 or spreadvirus or whatever into the bag, you are putting a number into the bag. This is because act1 and spreadvirus are numbers. They start as 0 and you add 1 to them at various points in your code.

It seems to me that you have put the wrong things in the bag. If you want a human to become infected if they pull out an infected item from the bag, then the bag needs to contain infected and uninfected items, not numbers.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering my question, JenB. I am not getting any error message from it. The problem is in the bag, probably when I share the virus from a zombie to a human, at the beginning and I try to store this information in humans' bags. This means that the virus is not spreading within the network and the humans cannot become infected.All the humans are susceptible (probably because I am creating them as susceptible and not due to the action chosen).

Comment: In the observer command, action1 and action3 (act1 and act3) are printed, so only the part with 'NOT WORKING' seems to be the real problem. The following part of code   `[spread set bag lput spreadvirus bag print "spreadvirus"
           if  [infected?] of choice                                 
               [become-infected] ]` is printed as well in the observer command, but no infected humans are in the network. And this means that, unfortunately, the procedure spreading is not doing what I should expect what it is supposed to do, i.e. as in the image shown.

Comment: This is the output that I got by adding on the top the command you suggested: `Neighbour count: 3
Bag at start: []
act3
Neighbour count: 1
Bag at start: [5]
spreading virus
Neighbour count: 1
Bag at start: [6 2] ...`. I cannot understand what the last print [6 2] means... I added more detailed information in the post on what is not working and what I should expect

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, JenB. Yes, I think you are right. What I thought was to add items in the bag, trying to distinguish if it was infected or not infected item depending on the neighbours (zombies can only do one action, i.e. spread the virus). But in the case of my code, I am just considering only humans... do you think this could be the problem? How could I can consider bag distinguish infected and uninfected items, not as numbers? Thank you for the time and help that you have provided me.

Comment: why don't you just add text like "Infected", "Medicine", etc to the bag and pull out `one-of` from the list?

Comment: How can I do what you suggest? Should I write: `set bag lput "medicine" bag`?

Comment: yes. Why did you ask? You should have tried it out. The only way to learn programming is by doing it.

Comment: I asked as I cannot use the following code to update the information `set spreadvirus spreadvirus + 1` if I use a string instead of a number, and I would need to keep the count of the items

Comment: You need to think about what you are using the count for and whether it needs to be in the bag at all. If it does, then ask a (new) question that fosuses on that aspect. As I have commented on several of your questions, you need to think more and code less. Build in small pieces, making that piece work before going on to the next piece.